# Eventbrite API: oauth2-login-example.php

Tags: php, oauth, eventbrite

I can't get the oauth2 working using the PHP library. I can get the jQuery library to work but I'd rather use PHP.

I get this error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/dotd/public_html/hub/examples/oauth2-login-example.php:22) in /home/dotd/public_html/hub/Eventbrite.php on line 162
```

You can see it here: http://www.daysofthedead.net/hub/examples/oauth2-login-example.php

It's the same code from github except I changed the `app_key` and `client_secret`.
( https://github.com/ryanjarvinen/eventbrite.php )

I have the "OAuth Redirect URI" pointing to http://www.daysofthedead.net/hub/examples/oauth2-login-example.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the code was attempting to trigger a header redirect (HTTP302) AFTER php had already written a portion of the response as an HTML page (HTTP200).

I've [relocated portions of the demo code](https://github.com/ryanjarvinen/eventbrite.php/commit/5011f2a663d31266e486be5ee0af52d7c5640985) so that the redirect (if needed) will be called BEFORE any of the page output is written.

Please try replacing your [OAuth2-login-example file](https://github.com/ryanjarvinen/eventbrite.php/blob/master/examples/oauth2-login-example.php).
Hope that works!

Comment: Thank you! Now it says `Please provide your Application Key in the URL as "?app_key=".`. Know how I can fix that?

Comment: Have you substituted your 'app_key' into the initialization code? ([See line 20 of the demo code](https://github.com/ryanjarvinen/eventbrite.php/blob/master/examples/oauth2-login-example.php#L20))

Comment: Yes, as I stated in my original post. :)

Comment: It works fine with my app key. Please [contact Eventbrite's developer support team](http://developer.eventbrite.com/contact-us/) for additional follow-up help.